# How do I convert SQL's convert(varchar,datefield,106) to LINQ?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How do I convert SQL's `convert(varchar,datefield,106)` to LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a string representation of a date by using ToString()

```
myDate.ToString()
```

and a date representation of a string by parsing it.

```
DateTime.Parse(myDateString)
```

You just need to include your conversion in your select clause.

```
from myRecord in myDataContext.MyTable
     select new {myStringDate = myRecord.myDate.ToString()};
```