# Project JS files

Tags: javascript

I want to protect my JS files using absolute path of the URL.

Please help me.

Comment: Please do not verbatim post answers from Stackoverflow under your own name to other forum sites: http://69.10.233.10/Forums/1640/Web-Development.aspx?fid=1640&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3085689&fr=1#xx3085689xx

Comment: If still posting answers elsewhere, you must comply with the CC-wiki license and attribute correctly, see http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403236/does-stackoverflow-own-the-content-i-post

Comment: I see that instead of attributing correctly (see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ ), you decided to change your name from "nbiswas_123" to "pewned_123", move to Singapore, and munge the questions (and answers). giving proper credit would be far easier, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot be done.

You can try to hide your JavaScript and CSS in obfuscated files, but since the user's browser needs to have it in order to display your page, the resourceful user can always distill it back from there.

**Update:**  The comments complain that I lifted this answer verbatim from a [forum site](http://69.10.233.10/Forums/1640/Web-Development.aspx?fid=1640&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3085689&fr=1#xx3085689xx). I would like to contend that it was the other way around. Check the time stamps and user names.

Comment: nice verbatim copy job:
http://69.10.233.10/Forums/1640/Web-Development.aspx?fid=1640&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3085689&fr=1#xx3085689xx

Comment: @Demi, both question and answer, but the answer missed the smiley.

Comment: WOW! I swear I posted it here first, and then it was copied to that forum.

Comment: One might suspect that "Niladri_Biswas" and "nbiswas_123" are related in some way...

Comment: Repeat offender?, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999377/linq-to-sql-date-format-problem and http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3082502/Re-Linq-to-sql-date-format-problem.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this with Apache mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.xyzxyz123.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bad.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css)$ /bad.js [NC,R]
```

This basically just looks for the referer, and if it's empty, or
not populated with your website (which the browser should pass in
the Referer: header) then it will return the /bad.js instead.
Just create a /bad.js which is empty, or contains junk code, etc.

A knowledgeable person could always figure out how to tamper with their
headers to pass the Referer header, so I wouldn't consider this a catch-all.

Hope this helps.